# RegEx: HTML whitelist

Tags: regex

Being weak on regular expressions, I've been working with them to improve.  One concept I've been trying to do is to remove all HTML elements except for a list of allowed ones.

I've managed to do the reverse -- remove a specified list of elements:

```
<\/?(strong|em|a)[^>]*>
```

However I want the opposite, and remove every element but.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/<(.|\n)*?>/g
```

[matches all HTML tags pairs including attributes in the tags](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm)

Exclude tags strong and em

```
(?!strong|em)
```

matches all HTML tags pairs but strong and em

```
<((?!strong|em).|\n)*?>
```

Comment: "<((?!strong|em).|\n)*?>" doesn't quite work: it won't match any tags that start with <strong or <em. For example: <stronger>test</stronger> and <embark>test</embark> aren't returned as matches.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regex for parsing [X]HTML.

Doubly especially definitely NEVER use regex for parsing [X]HTML as a security measure.

An HTML parser (or tidier followed by an XML parser) is the only workable approach for whitelisting.

> /<(.|\n)*?>/g matches all HTML tags pairs including attributes in the tags

No.

```
<a href=">" onmouseover="attackCode()">
```

and a thousand other possibilities, both valid and malformed-but-the-browser-will-still-understand-it.

Answer (score 4):

[Do NOT try parsing with regular expressions](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html)

Instead use a [real parser](http://grom.zeminvaders.net/html-sanitizer)

Comment: This is not meant as an actualy production implementation, but as a learning experiment.

Comment: Fair enough, just had to post this as warning to others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PCRE, use (?!*elements*) instead of (*elements*).

Comment: Halfway there. It still matches the closing tag. e.g. <strong>test</strong> returns <strong>test